# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list throwing error in html line

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

can anyone tell me what's wrong in this line?

Template:

```
<c:forEach items="${templateList}" var ="temp">
   <td>
      <button onclick = "edit(${temp.id});" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" title="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</button>
   </td>
   <td>
      <button data-target="#myModal2" title="Attach Link" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></button>
   </td>
   <td>
      <button data-target="" data-toggle="modal" title="duplicate" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button>
   </td>
</c:forEach>
```

and as well as this function

```
<script>
   function edit(id){
      $.get("get/" + id,function(result){
         $("#myModal1").html(result);
         alert("dnrbufevc ");
      });
   }
</script>
```

Comment: Why cant you use `ng-click` and use your function inside your controller?

Comment: @Senal actually taglib I am using so I am just selecting single value from the list of value that's why I want mandatorialy go with $ selector

Comment: Does ${temp.id} render as an actual string when you inspect the button? Otherwise you're just sending a string to the JS not the ID you're intending

Comment: Can you update your answer with the whole html

Comment: @Doug <c:forEach items="${templateList}" var ="temp">
<td><button onclick = "edit(${temp.id});" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal"  title="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</button></td>
<td><button data-target="#myModal2"  title="Attach Link" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-paperclip"></i></button></td>
<td><button data-target="" data-toggle="modal" title="duplicate" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-copy"></i></button></td>


</c:forEach>   here is my whole code

Comment: @Senal please find the above code

Comment: @ram Edit your question - add your code/html to the question.

Answer (score 1):

Change your template for `onClick` to the following

```
<button onclick = "edit('${temp.id}')" data-target="#myModal1" data-toggle="modal" title="Edit" class="btn btn-success btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i>Edit</button>
```

Make sure to have single quotes around `'${temp.id}'` so that javascript will treat it as a string literal.

Comment: I don't want that '${temp.id}' as string literal that is actal id int type

Comment: What do you get inside your `onclick` method as `id` after doing that change?